# how to make simple_form work with twitter-bootstrap-rails; form in general in bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, validation, simple-form

1) How to build forms using simple form and twitter-bootstrap-rails so that they show cool bootstrap style validation errors?

2) How to build forms in twitter-bootstrap-rails so that they show cool bootstrap style validation errors?

3) I tried building form with simple_form. But validation is not showing any error messages. I am trying to add validation on User Model and Form generated by `Devise`

Techs: Rails 3.2.7.rc1, 1.9.2, twitter-ootstrap-rails 2.1.1, simple-form 2.0.2

code:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>

        <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :fname, :placeholder=>"First name", :input_html => { :class => "enroll_input span4"} %>
    <%= f.input :lname, :placeholder=>"Last name", :input_html => { :class => "enroll_input span4"} %>
    <%= f.input :email,:placeholder=>"Email",:input_html => { :class => "enroll_input span4"}  %>
    <%= f.input :password, :placeholder=>"Password",:input_html => { :class => "enroll_input span4"} %>
    <div class="enroll_button"> <%= f.submit "  Enroll  ", :class=>"btn btn-primary pull-right btn-large" %></div>
        <% end %>
```

I am not sure though if this not working or `jquery` is not working.

Comment: Please show some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Holger Just: update code

Comment: Please, make sure you are using `bootstrap` as a default wrapper for this form. See `config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap` in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`. To generate simple_form config with bootstrap wrapper use this command: `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

Comment: Checked everything is at its place..

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<%= f.input :email do %>
   <%= f.input_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find notes about integration of the two, example app, the live app:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/#twitter-bootstrap

Comment: went thru it but everything is as it is supposed to be.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

**simple_form + bootstrap**

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form